# Are GPars Actors fault tolerant

Tags: actor, gpars

Actors in GPars have their own message queue (mail box). Say an actor is having 15 pending messages and suddenly system goes down(say due to power failure). What will happen to those 15 messages. Will the message queue be restored automatically when system is up and running again? Or messages in the queue will be lost?

Answer (score 3):

GPars actors do not provide fault-tolerant messaging at the moment.

Comment: What about `@ActiveMethod`s? I think they do.